# HTML5 localStorage with a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, local-storage

I've been trying to use localStorage with a textarea in my webpage (to no avail).

My save script is as follows:

```
$(function() {
 var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
 editor.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  window.localStorage["TextEditorData"] = editor.value;
 });
});
```

My load script is as follows:

```
$window.load(function () {
 var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
 if (window.localStorage["TextEditorData"]) {
  editor.value = window.localStorage["TextEditorData"];
 }
});
```

My HTML5 code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data-load.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/data-save.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="editor.focus()">
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something obvious here? I *did* manage to get it to work when I used a contenteditable div instead of a textarea and with editor.innerHTML instead of editor.value but I need to use a textarea for this particular webpage. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error Nick Craver pointed out, and it does work in jsFiddle. For some reason it still doesn't work in my webpage though.

Comment: Okay, I've got it going now. Not entirely sure why though, all I did was change the JavaScript variable 'editor' to 'ta' while leaving the textarea id as 'editor'. Oh well, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some parenthesis on your `if()`, this:

```
 if window.localStorage["TextEditorData"] {
```

Should be:

```
 if (window.localStorage["TextEditorData"]) {
```

Currently it's throwing a syntax error.  [Here's a version of your code with the above fix](http://jsfiddle.net/9KBWF/), working :)

Comment: Why have you attached `jquey-ui.css` to your fiddle? Is there a specific reason?